# How to specify spec names to screenshots for each test run in protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, allure

I am using protractor framework & jasmine-allure-reporter to create report and take screenshot.

```js
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
      resultsDir: 'allure-results'
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function (done) {
      browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
        allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
          return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
        }, 'image/png')();
        done();
      })
    });
  }
```

Is there a provision to customize the screenshot name for each test? Currently it has some random number as the image name(`0a8bbc5e-35ee-4d7f-be8b-532fe4a1b4a8-attachment.png`) instead i want something like this (`<specname>.png`). Is it possible to do that? Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
    var timeStamp = today.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + today.getDate() + '-' + today.getFullYear() + '-' + today.getHours() + 'h-' + today.getMinutes() + 'm-' + today.getSeconds() + 's';
    ScreenShotName = 'MaGE_Admin' + '-' + timeStamp;
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    jasmine.getEnv().topSuite().afterEach({
        fn: async function () {
            try {
                await browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                    allure.createAttachment(ScreenShotName, new Buffer.from(png, 'base64'));
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: please provide a little more info on how your answer solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
      resultsDir: 'allure-results'
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function (done) {
      browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
        allure.createAttachment(exports.config.multiCapabilities.name, function () {
          return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
        }, 'image/png')();
        done();
      })
    });
  }
```

That worked for me.

Comment: See that I using multicapabilities, but if you are using just capabilities, replace that and should work too.

> exports.config.capabilities.name